# Issues with managing DataGridView rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

A quick introduction to the source of my problem:

I have a `DataGridView` that's the child of a resizable `Panel`, which can be adjusted by the user's mouse input. When the `Panel` is resized, the `DataGridView`'s size is mirrored along with it. The idea is that, instead of the columns and rows of the grid auto-sizing to fit the contents of the cells or gridspace, the number of columns and rows will be determined by the size of the grid. The width and height of the rows and columns are pre-determined and don't need to be adjusted. The point of this is to let the user quickly adjust row and column quantity. This is best demonstrated by a short clip of the code in action: [Resizing Panel](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6ZnFFzx83I)

To accomplish this, I check if the panel is resizing, and, depending if it's shrinking or growing, columns are adjusted accordingly. There's some magic going on here, but it essentially looks like this:

```
if(panel_width_is_growing)
{
    if(margin >= growing_threshold)
    {
        DataGridViewColumn column = new DataGridViewColumn();
        column.Name = "Run " + (dataGridView.Columns.Count + 1).ToString();
        column.HeaderText = "Run " + (dataGridView.Columns.Count + 1).ToString();

        dataGridView.Columns.Add(column);
    }
}

if(!panel_width_is_growing)
{
    if(margin <= shrinking_threshold)
    {
        dataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(dataGridView.Columns.Count - 1);
    }
}
```

Now, this is where my issue comes in. I do the *exact* same thing to add and remove rows from the grid, though with adjusted margins and thresholds to account for row dimension instead of column dimension. The only difference is I'm looking at the height of the panel as opposed to the width:

```
if(panel_height_is_growing)
{
    if(margin >= row_threshold)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
        row.HeaderCell.Value =  (dataGridView.Rows.Count + 1).ToString();
        dataGridView.Rows.Add(row);              
    }                
}
```

And no rows appear... I can't figure out the issue. The code is hitting all the necessary lines, verified by breakpoints and stepping. The RowCount property is never incremented and no alarms go off, as the whole thing is wrapped in a try catch block. There's no binding associated with the grid or special functions that overload default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with typing (a real boneheaded oversight). `DataGridViewColumn` doesn't have a default cell template, so trying to add rows to the column failed. Using `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` cleared it right up.